# Rate of function [Python]

Tags: python, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to change the frequency at which I enter to the function `def detect_marker(self, msg)`

Imagine that my code is like this (I deleted a lot of lines because this way would be easier to read):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import division
import rospy
import sys
from std_msgs.msg import String
from std_msgs.msg import Empty
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from ardrone_autonomy.msg import  Navdata


import threading
import tf
import time
from std_msgs.msg import Empty
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image, CameraInfo, CompressedImage
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
import cv2
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped
from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose

import numpy as np
import math

import time
from time import sleep


from ar_track_alvar_msgs.msg import AlvarMarkers




class gonnaGetDown():
    
    
    def __init__(self):
        

        self.velocity_publisher = rospy.Publisher('/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=10)
        self.orientation_publisher = rospy.Publisher('/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=10)

        print "b"

        global u_x_k, u_x_k_pre
        u_x_k, u_x_k_pre = 0, 0

        rospy.Subscriber('/ar_pose_marker', AlvarMarkers, self.detect_marker)

    def detect_marker(self, msg):
        print "c"

        u_x_k_pre = u_x_k
        u_x_k = u_x_k +1

        if not msg.markers:
            print "Tag not found"
            vel_msg = Twist()

            vel_msg.linear.x = 0.0
            vel_msg.linear.y = 0.0
            vel_msg.linear.z = 0.0
            vel_msg.angular.x = 0.0
            vel_msg.angular.y = 0.0
            vel_msg.angular.z = 0.0

            self.velocity_publisher.publish(vel_msg)
            return
        else:
            marker = msg.markers[0]
            print "d"

            
            self.velocity_publisher.publish(vel_msg)

            

            
if __name__ == '__main__':

    rospy.init_node('go_down', anonymous=True)
    


    try:
        rate = rospy.Rate(0.0001) 
        gonna_get_down = gonnaGetDown()
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            
            print "a"
            
            rate.sleep()


    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        rospy.loginfo("Node terminated.")
```

The most basic rqt graph is this https://imgur.com/LlWrhUW (ar_track_alvar node posts on /ar_pose_marker topic)

Leaving the code like that, it prints: a --> b --> c --> d --> c --> d --> c --> d --> c --> ... and so on

But the time between d's is 1 second. What if I want to make that much faster, like 10 times per second? Where do I change the frequency?

Thanks :D

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313035/rate-of-function-%5Bpython%5D/) by [Dylan](https://answers.ros.org/users/31995/dylan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2019-01-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Isha Dijcks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38758/isha-dijcks/) on 2019-01-17**:
Have you seen [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/264812/explanation-of-rospyrate/) question, it gives a good explanation on rospy.Rate.

**Comment by [Dylan](https://answers.ros.org/users/31995/dylan/) on 2019-01-17**:
But changing the rospy.Rate would change the rate of the function gonnaGetDown, and I would like to stay in detect_marker but at a much higher frequency. If I enter to gonnaGetDown, how can I define the global variables and to maintain there values between gonnaGetDown and detect_marker?

**Comment by [Dylan](https://answers.ros.org/users/31995/dylan/) on 2019-01-17**:
I mean, I need them to stay in their past values. If they enter to gonnaGetDown, they're always going to be =0

**Comment by [Isha Dijcks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38758/isha-dijcks/) on 2019-01-17**:
`detect_marker()` is a callback of the subscriber to the topic `/ar_pose_marker`. If you want to have the callback triggered more often, you'd have to publish more on that topic or increase the rate with which you check for messages on that topic if you are missing some.

**Comment by [Dylan](https://answers.ros.org/users/31995/dylan/) on 2019-01-17**:
And how can I do that @IshaDijcks?

**Comment by [Isha Dijcks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38758/isha-dijcks/) on 2019-01-17**:
You could increase the rate of the node that publishes to that topic. However I am not completely sure what it is you are trying to accomplish. What exactly is your goal and why?

**Comment by [Dylan](https://answers.ros.org/users/31995/dylan/) on 2019-01-17**:
If I just change the rospy.Rate to 10, the program prints "a" 10 times, then "c" and then "d"

**Comment by [Dylan](https://answers.ros.org/users/31995/dylan/) on 2019-01-17**:
I want to enter more times to that function so I get much more samples per second. I'm trying to control a quadcopter. I don't know how to change the rate of the ar_track_alvar node

**Comment by [Joe Dyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/39484/joe-dyer/) on 2019-01-17**:
the only thing that rospy.Rate affects is that one loop, which only prints a. The subscriber callback has its own thread in rospy, so the issue has nothing to do with the subscribing rate, but rather the rate the publisher publishes. What is publishing to the topic /ar_pose_marker?

**Comment by [Joe Dyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/39484/joe-dyer/) on 2019-01-17**:
can you run:
rostopic echo /ar_pose_marker
and verify that this is only publishing at every second

**Comment by [Dylan](https://answers.ros.org/users/31995/dylan/) on 2019-01-17**:
@JoeDyer I added an image of the rqt_graph (the link because I didn't have permission to upload a picture). ar_track_alvar node posts on /ar_pose_marker topic

**Comment by [Joe Dyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/39484/joe-dyer/) on 2019-01-17**:
It appears that ar_pose_marker is published through a callback from subscribing to the image. However, in c++, ros doesn't handle callbacks in a separate thread. Can you tell me what the value for max_frequency you have in ar_track_alvar/cfg/Param.cfg?

**Comment by [Dylan](https://answers.ros.org/users/31995/dylan/) on 2019-01-17**:
Solved, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As has been mentioned by @Isha Dijcks the `detect_marker` function in your code is a message callback. It gets executed every time your node receives a message on it's topic, in this case it's own execution takes an insignificant amount of time so the rate it is executed at is entirely depended on the rate of messages being published on that topic.

If you want to speed this up you don't need to do anything to this code, you need to change the settings for [ar_track_alvar](http://wiki.ros.org/ar_track_alvar) that controls the rate at which it publishes marker pose detection messages.

There is a non-documented (as far as I can tell) configuration parameter [(see source code)](https://github.com/ros-perception/ar_track_alvar/blob/melodic-devel/ar_track_alvar/nodes/IndividualMarkers.cpp#L530) for this node called `max_frequency` which defaults to 8 (Hz). By adjusting this you should be able to increase the rate of your callback function.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dylan](https://answers.ros.org/users/31995/dylan/) on 2019-01-17**:
Solved, thanks !!!

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-01-17**:
@Dylan if this answered your question, then could you please click on the check mark (✓) to the left of the answer